# Problema al mostrar en consola el contenido de una cola en JAVA

Tags: java

lo que quiero hacer es que  los valores que introduce el usuario en una cola se muestren por medio de iterator; sin embargo cuando corro el programa no ejecuta el método imprimir es como si mi `hasNext` no cachara nada de info.¿ A qué se podría deber esto?, pego el código,gracias por responder:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class ColaScanner {
    Queue<String> cS=new LinkedList<>();
    Iterator<String> it =cS.iterator();
    private static Scanner obDatos;
    private String d;
    private Object element;

    public void obDatos() {
        for(int i=0; i<3;i++) {
        System.out.println("Ingresa los elementos de la lista:");
        d= obDatos.nextLine();
        cS.add(d);
         }
    }
    public void imprimir() { 
        System.out.println("El contenido es:");

        while(it.hasNext()) {
            element = it.next();
            System.out.println("elementos"+ element);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ColaScanner dato= new ColaScanner();
        obDatos=new Scanner(System.in);
        dato.obDatos();
        dato.imprimir();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error que arrojaba se debe a que inicializabas el `iterator` después de declarar el `LinkedList` y en ese momento el objeto esta vacío, ya después en ningún momento asignas el valor del `iterator` con la lista ya llena, prueba inicializando el iterador antes de imprimir los elementos ya con la lista llena, de la siguiente manera:

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ColaScanner {
    Queue<String> cS=new LinkedList<String>();

    private static Scanner obDatos;
    private String d;
    private Object element;

    public void obDatos() {
        for(int i=0; i<3;i++) {
        System.out.println("Ingresa los elementos de la lista:");
        d= obDatos.nextLine();
        cS.add(d);
         }
    }
    public void imprimir() { 
        System.out.println("El contenido es:");
        //Inicializar el iterador ya con la lista con objetos.
        Iterator<String> it =cS.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()) {
            element = it.next();
            System.out.println("elementos"+ element);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ColaScanner dato= new ColaScanner();
        obDatos=new Scanner(System.in);
        dato.obDatos();
        dato.imprimir();
    }
}
```

Comment: J.Castro muchas gracias por tu ayuda :)

Comment: @MichelleArezuSama de nada :) si te sirvio la respuesta marcala como aceptada! Saludos